# Logging application messages and unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: logging

We are starting a new ASP.NET 3.5 MVC application (with Entity Framework, etc). The application will handle exceptions at method level and log them. Unhandled and Runtime exceptions should also be logged.
The logging module/framework should log **BOTH** application error/debug/info messages and unhandled exceptions.

**Options:**

- EL 4.1 Logging Application Block
- ASP.NET Health Monitoring
- log4net Framework : http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html
- NLog
- ELMAH Framework : http://code.google.com/p/elmah/
- Custom Logging (using [HandleError] filter, OnActionExecuted event of Controller and OnError event in the Global.asax)
- **OTHERS?**

**Please compare the frameworks.**

Which will be the most suitable choice ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There are **a lot** of logging and tracing tools out there for .NET, including our very own [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/products/smartinspect/) tool. We've collected a list of logging tools and posted them to [DotNetLogging.com](http://www.dotnetlogging.com). But as John already wrote, without providing more details about your application and logging needs, it's hard to recommend a specific tool or solution.